# DrRacket function call: expected a function after the open parenthesis, but found a number

Tags: function, racket

I just started computer science at a local university and all is going well but I can't seem to figure out why this code (that's presented to me in a power point presentation) throws me an error since this is what my professor showed us in class. The point of it is to make the rocket start at the bottom of the scene and stop at the top but I keep getting these function errors in the lines define H0, define H10, (-500(* 3 t)). Code is below:

```
(require 2htdp/image)
(require 2htdp/universe)

(define width 500)
(define height 500)

(define e-scene(empty-scene width height))
(define rocket (image))
(define rocket-x(/ width 2))

(define H0 (-500(* 3 0)))
(define H10 (-500(* 3 10)))
(check-expect(height 0) H0)
(check-expect(height 10)H10)

(define(altitude t)
(-500(*3 t)))


(define img0 (place-image rocket rocket-x (height 0)e-scene))
(define img45 (place-image rocket rocket-x (height 45) e-scene))
(check-expect(create-rocket-scene 0)img0)
(check-expect(create-rocket-scene 45)img45)

(define (create-rocket-scene t)
  (place-image rocket rocket-x(height t)e-scene))

(animate create-rocket-scene)
```

Comment: The two lines you mentioned have a syntax problem since the inner expression is not valid in Racket. Look [here](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define.html) for more information.

Comment: `-500` is a number, `- 500` isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Scheme list expression should look like this: `(procedure arg1 arg2 ...)`.

Expression `(define H0 (-500(* 3 0)))` is read as `(define H0 (-500 (* 3 0)))` and `-500` is not procedure (function), so it throws error. Expression `(define H10 (-500(* 3 10)))` has the same problem.

Just rewrite these two lines as `(define H0 (- 500 (* 3 0)))` and `(define H10 (- 500 (* 3 10)))` and also add spaces to other expressions- maybe they work, but are very hard to read now.